# Is there a way to show the the user available overloads for powershell class constructors at object creation and not having them pipe it to GM?

Tags: powershell, class

I am looking at grouping some functions into classes in PowerShell and I would like to show the different constructor overloads to the user.

Is there a way to show what overloads are available for the person using the class while they are typing it out instead of them having to pipe an object to `Get-Member`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting `[<type>]::new` at the command line - *without* `()` - shows all constructor overloads (if any) for type `<type>` (requires PowerShell v5+).

For instance:

```
PS> [datetime]::new  # do NOT append '()'

OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                                                            
-------------------                                                                                                                                            
datetime new(long ticks)                                                                                                                                       
datetime new(long ticks, System.DateTimeKind kind)                                                                                                             
datetime new(int year, int month, int day)                                                                                                                     
datetime new(int year, int month, int day, System.Globalization.Calendar calendar)                                                                             
datetime new(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second)                                                                                   
datetime new(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, System.DateTimeKind kind)                                                         
datetime new(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, System.Globalization.Calendar calendar)                                           
datetime new(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond)                                                                  
datetime new(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond, System.DateTimeKind kind)                                        
datetime new(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond, System.Globalization.Calendar calendar)                          
datetime new(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond, System.Globalization.Calendar calendar, System.DateTimeKind kind)
```

Note that the same technique also works for *method* overloads; e.g.:

````
PS> (Get-Date).ToString # do NOT append '()'

OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                                                            
-------------------                                                                                                                                            
string ToString()                                                                                                                                              
string ToString(string format)                                                                                                                                 
string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                               
string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                
string IFormattable.ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider)                                                                             
string IConvertible.ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ```
````